# How to determine which user control is calling command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Relative new to MVVM - I realize this is simple question but can't seem to find the answer.

I have 4 grouped radio buttons that when one is selected will show its associated options. I assume these 4 radio buttons should be linked to the same viewmodel command which in this case is called `UpdateIndex`.

How do I determine ***which*** of the radio buttons is calling the `UpdateIndex` so that I can take appropriate action and show the appropriate options?

Note that my `UpdateIndex` and `UpdateIndexExecute` does get called correctly from my radio button command binding, I just don't know how to determine which radio button is calling it. I assume it has to do with `CommandParameter` - but not sure how to access it from the viewmodel.

An example of my radio button:

```
<RadioButton
    Content="Option 1"
    GroupName="GroupHeader"
    Command="{Binding UpdateIndex}" />
```

Code snippet of my  command being called from the radio button when clicked...

```
void UpdateIndexExecute()
{

}

bool CanUpdateIndex()
{
   return true;
}

public ICommand UpdateIndex
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(UpdateTabIndexExecute, CanUpdateTabIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: `CommandParameter` is the parameter that is passed to the command as parameter, that is `void UpdateIndexExecute(/* this right here */);` (I guess there is a `RelayCommand<T>`?)

Comment: note that there is also [`ElementName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) if you don't want to use the ViewModel to trigger changes in the view. Another thing to check is [`Triggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a true MVVM implementation, you won't know which RadioButton executed the command, because the ViewModel should not have any information about the View.  User Controls fall squarely in the category of "things that only exist within the View, not the ViewModel."  You should instead pass something meaningful to the ViewModel.

You are correct there are ways to pass information into an ICommand using the "CommandParameter" of a Command Binding.  For that, you would use the "generic" form of the RelayCommand ([RelayCommand](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs)) class, where "T" represents the type of object you are passing as a parameter.

If you're just trying to pass an index as a parameter, I imagine it'll look something like this:

```
<!-- We are passing index "1" as a parameter -->
<RadioButton Content="Option 1"  GroupName="GroupHeader" 
             Command="{Binding UpdateIndex, CommandParameter=1}"/>
```

Then in your ViewModel:

```
void UpdateIndexExecute(int index)
{

}
    
bool CanUpdateIndex(int index)
{
    return true;
}

public ICommand UpdateIndex 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return new RelayCommand<int>(UpdateTabIndexExecute, CanUpdateTabIndex); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: OK - I get the logic of the view control only remains in the view and shouldn't make it back to the viewmodel and that only model data and the like should make it back. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding the command, you can bind the content, use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to handle changes made by the control.