# Is there a way to know in code behind 'xaml.cs' if the command was fired by another control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

This is my button template.

```
`<Button
    Name="Save"
    Command="{Binding Save}">
</Button>`
```

Now the main window also uses the Save command(key binding) when the user uses the shortcut key ctrl save.
I want to know in my template if the command was fired by another control.

Sample code:

```
`<Window>
   <KeyBinding
            Key="S" 
            Command="{Binding Save}"
            Modifiers="Ctrl" />
    <Template:ButtonSave/>
</Window>`
```

Comment: You could use `CommandParameter` property that will pass on the value to your execute method.
Or you can use two separate commands that would eventually end-up calling the same execute implementation. Second one is bit more cleaner if you ask me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine which user control is calling command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16567683/how-to-determine-which-user-control-is-calling-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I it certainly possible to use `CommandParameter` property with the `bool` value in the xaml and that value would end-up as a parameter in your command's execute method.
Then you can decide what to do based on that value.

But the boolean parameter is in most cases anti-pattern and actually hides the fact that you are essentially dealing with two somewhat different methods, conceals your intent, etc...

Say you that on the `CTRL+S` you just want to save the data and on the button you also want to close the window, then this would be more clean approach (in my opinion):

```
private void ExecuteSave()
{
    // Do your stuff
}

private void ExecuteSaveAndClose()
{
    ExecuteSave();
    RequestClose();
}

Save = new Command(ExecuteSave);
SaveAndClose = new Command(ExecuteSaveAndClose);
```

And in the xaml:

```
<Window>
   <KeyBinding
       Key="S" Modifiers="Ctrl"
       Command="{Binding Save}" />
    <Template:ButtonSave/>
</Window>

<Button Command="{Binding SaveAndClose}" />
```